# android Volley GET method with HashMap parameters

Tags: android, get, android-volley

i am making webservice calling using volly
my method is as below

```
 Map<String, String> MyData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        MyData.put(pam1, parm1value);


        JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject(MyData);
        System.out.println(parameters + " *** PRM");//this prints data
        JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                "myurl",
                parameters, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                //TODO: handle success
                System.out.println(response+"***");

            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                //TODO: handle failure
            }
        });
        System.out.println("REQ "+jsonRequest+"");//not prints parms 
        Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx).add(jsonRequest);
```

But, when running app i got

```
 [220] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for [my url]
```

I also tried with `StringRequest` with hashmap parms but same problem

Comment: Print the URL and check that it is correct or not

Comment: Its the issue on the server side. You can check [this](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html) for more

Comment: issue is from server side..check your url

Comment: Are you try custom request?

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this steps while making volley request**

[Volley Request Step By Step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45590943/6022340)

> change method to GET from POST.